# Url friendly .htaccess and Joomla 3.4

Tags: joomla-3.x, server

I have problems with the url, are duplicating to google

```
http://www.villadelia.es/blog-de-bodas/sofia-y-ruben-una-boda-con-mucha-poesia
```

delete "blog-de-bodas"

```
http://www.villadelia.es/sofia-y-ruben-una-boda-con-mucha-poesia
```

and works.

I revised final of the archive .htaccess and is the same than another pages

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

if you dont mind help me.

Comment: DO YOU HAVE ANY SEF COMPONENT INSTALLED?

Comment: @fruppel Please don't shout on Stack Exchange (i.e. no all-caps). Thank you!

Comment: sry, I was just imitating the questioner ;-)

Comment: Title fixed to the general style

Comment: Fruppel thank you. No I not have any component sef only joomla

Comment: Hello virtualsets, please try to improve your question, to make it more meaningful. It's not easy to understand what is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla, Sef Url cannot customized in .htaccess.

Url Routing is managed at Joomla level. You can work with the standard router or install an extension.

In both cases, router defines a path to access content according to your navigational menu organization.

You can have several valid access paths. Google discovers content navigating all published links. Thus, you have to restrict what it discovers.

If you want to only publish certain types of Urls, then you have to restrict public access paths.

PD: Even though, many valid access paths may exist to an object. In your example, you show an Url to an article in a category and the same article without category.

Comment: Hello and thank you Anibal. Why this not past whith another website www.video-boda.es in the same server  with the same .htaccess. This are generating problems with google that find more articles.

Comment: Anibal where you think that I can find the problem, please put me a image.

Comment: You can have several valid access paths. Google discovers content navigating all published links. Thus, you have to restrict what it discovers. I guess you have several menu items for the same articles.

Comment: Anibal this past with all the 43 articles. I only have 5 menuitems. I check disable all the modules  and all the menuitems minus "home" and "blog", and also happens. Sorry my bad english

Answer (score 1):

For the people that have my problem I find a solution, is very crazy and sorry my bad english

[image]

Only I change the article that link the menu item from number 1 to number 2

in this moments  works well, it is not a problem of .htaccess and I see the article that the two is in the same category and not understand nothing, but works.

http://www.villadelia.es/blog-de-bodas/sofia-y-ruben-una-boda-con-mucha-poesia

than withought "blog-de-bodas"

Thank you and hope help any people the next time.